# Change default path for VS Code workspace files [workspaceStorage]?

Tags: apache-http-server, java, visual-studio-code, tomcat, workspace

I am desperately trying to debug a Java Tomcat application, run in a local network of an enterprise, using VS Code, and am using a Tomcat extension to do the job:

- The Tomcat extension saves a temporary copy of the Tomcat server and a web application in the workspace folder of VS Code:

  ```
  \\networkDriveAddress...\...\name.home\Redirected_Profile\AppData\Code\User\workspaceStorage\ProjectId\adashen.vscode-tomcat\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.4DEVELOPMENT\webapps\myWebAppName\...
  ```

It seems Tomcat or Windows refuses to process this because the path to the java classes [below] is too long and I assume this because:

```
...\myWebAppName\WEB-INF\classes\myPackage\mySubPackage\mySubSubPackage\myClass.class
```

- It works if I deploy a webapp with a small class tree [shorter paths]
- It works if I delete the folder with classes from `myWebAppName`, leaving only `index.html`
- If I try to copy around `...\classes\...`, Windows refuses to copy because the path is too long

How can I change the default workspaceStorage for VS Code:

- **From:** `\\networkDriveAddress\...\...\User\`
- **To:** `E:\wspace\`

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49326)?

Comment: @Ramhound thank you, somehow I was not able to google this... although I have just found from the tomcat extensions's source code that it can be solved by setting appropriate tomcat extensions parameters, I believe your link answers the original question. I am going to try out and come back a bit later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I change the default workspaceStorage for VS Code:
>
> - From: \networkDriveAddress......\User\
> - To: E:\wspace\

You should be able to use `code --user-data-dir E:\wspace\`, however, that will change the directory for all user data.  `workspaceStorage` is just one storage element that Visual Studio code uses.

Sources:

- [Modify vscode `workspaceStorage` folder path #49326](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49326)
- [Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)
- [Modify vscode `workspaceStorage` folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187662/modify-vscode-workspacestorage-folder-path)